# Не завершается регистрация на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Сделал все что нужно было. Перешел по ссылке в письме, изменил пароль. Затем вылезла страница с кнопками и картинками что тут да как  и я завершил регистрацию. Но кнопка завершить регистрацию висит до сих пор, и вопросы я типа анонимом задаю.

Comment: Не беспокойтесь, наверняка починят.  )

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, проделали ли вы все шаги из публикации [про восстановлении доступа к учетным записям ХэшКода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24/)?

Comment: у меня не было аккаунта на этом хешкоде